# Set output Language of Get-Acl

Tags: powershell, acl, multilingual

I´m working on a powershell script that should among others delete privileges of a given network share.

**I use:**

```
 $folder = "Path\To\Folder\on\Share"

 $acl = Get-ACL -Path $Folder

 #Remove inheritance but copy ACE
 $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)

 Set-Acl -Path $folder -AclObject $acl

 $acl = Get-ACL -Path $Folder

 $accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer","Read",,,"Allow")

 $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule)

 Set-Acl -Path $folder -AclObject $acl
```

This should delete inheritence while preserving the existing privileges and then delete all rights of `"BUILTIN\Users"`.

Unfortunately my systems language is german so writing `"BUILTIN\Users"` or `"<OUR DOMAIN>\Users"` does not work as it translates the output of Get-ACL automaticly and I have to write the German translation `"VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer"`.

This is very unpleasent as the script should run on serveral systems with different OS languages and I would have to write one rule for every language.

**Question**
How can I force powershell to output in English? Is there a better way ?

Comment: Use well-known Security Identifiers instead of group names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Security Identifier of the builtin groups instead (always the same):

```
$BuiltinUsersSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 'S-1-5-32-545'
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $BuiltinUsersSid,"Read","Allow"
```

---

As [shown by Martin Brandl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587555/712649) you can use WMI to find user or group accounts based on SID, but you can also *translate* a `SecurityIdentifier` object to an account like so if you want the localized name:

```
PS> $BuiltinUsersSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 'S-1-5-32-545'
PS> $BuiltinUsersGroup = $BuiltinUsersSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
PS> $BuiltinUsersGroup.Value # This would output VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer on a system with german locale
BUILTIN\Users
```

Comment: I like this more then my WMI approach .

Comment: I adapted this Solution. Thank your very much for your help Mathias and @MartinBrandl !

Comment: @MartinBrandl You can also get the account name without WMI, check my update

Comment: Thanks for that as well. This will make it to my snippet collection ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As [Mathias R. Jessen mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), you should *work with Secure Identifiers*. Here is a [list of Well-known SIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649(v=vs.85).aspx). You probably want to do something like this:

```
# ...
$sidName = ([wmi]"Win32_SID.SID='S-1-5-32-545'").AccountName
$accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($sidName,"Read",,,"Allow")
```

Comment: I got the SID of the by 1. $AdObj = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Domain Users") 2.  $strSID = $AdObj.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]) 3. $strSID.Value

Inserting the resulting SID in your code results no errors but it does not Change the file permissions as if there was no user provided

Comment: oh, I forgot the domain name, try: `$sidName = '{0}\{1}' -f ([wmi]"Win32_SID.SID='S-1-5-32-545'").ReferencedDomainName, ([wmi]"Win32_SID.SID='S-1-5-32-545'").AccountName`

Comment: The Output of $sidName is correct (<MyDomain>\Domain Users) but the problem still exists

Comment: After typing everything again it works like a charm, Thank you very much